# GWT project doesn't build server side code

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, ant

I'm novice in GWT and trying to build my first GWT application.
I downloaded GWT 2.6.1 and created demo application ('mydemo') using webApplicationCreator.
It works perferct on my developer machine. Then, I want to deploy this application to production server.  I installed Apache Tomcat which requires war package. Well, I created war package. But it doesn't contain file mydemo.jar with server-side code (GreetingServiceImpl).

So, I need to configure build.xml to create .jar file with server side of my GWT application. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

`webApplicationCreator`'s generated Ant file compiles your classes to `WEB-INF/classes`, it doesn't package them in a JAR.

If you have an error on your "production server", I'd suggest you ask about that error and server.